# Android: Get Value from Grid View

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview

Hi I currently have a Grid View, Which I Inserted an Array through an Adapter onto the Grid View.

I am using this method currently:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    }
```

As demonstrated within the Android Documentation, Specifically I need to find the value set within the field of the grid that the user touch/clicked. Is this done through using the position variable within on item click e.g?

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // DO something

        }
```

Or is it done manually ? Kind of at logger head's with this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I am first using a String Array and then using an Array Adapter to set the values into the Grid

Comment: Ok. I answered with a snippet of what I think you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:
         String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

inside your onItemClick where adapter is the AdadpterView

Answer (score 0):

The `v` argument in your `onItemClick()` method is a reference to the View that was clicked.
Simply cast that into a `TextView` and get the text:

`String text = ((TextView)v).getText().toString();`

Comment: No problem at all! Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Thanks for the help however the solution looked like this in the Program. String value = (String) ((TextView)view).getText(); I just wondered would it be possible to use the string within a case statement so that a variety of different functions can be done depending upon the value ?

Comment: @CatLikeOlive0 Sure! Just do `switch(value) ...`